# SQL injection authentication bypass

Tags: web-application, php, sql-injection, mysql, injection

I am testing a SQLi login bypass on the PHP code below:

```
if(isset($_POST["login"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $sql="select * from users where login='{$_POST["login"]}' and password='{$_POST["password"]}'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)
        echo "<h1>Login Success!</h1>";
    else
        echo "<h1>Invalid Login!</h1>";
}
```

I am using `admin' --` as the login field in order to bypass the login without entering a password, but it doesn't work. However, when I tried using `admin' -- ' --` instead it works.

How and why does the second cheat work but not the first one?

These are the server-side codes when I enter the two cheats:

```
$sql="select * from users where login='admin' --' and password='{$_POST["password"]}'"; 
$sql="select * from users where login='admin' -- ' --' and password='{$_POST["password"]}'";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In mysql you need a white space after comment marker. Just put one whitespace character after `--`.

```
select * from users where login='admin' -- now you can add comment
```

Generally add trash character after the whitespace against trim function. Like;

`admin' -- xx`

Comment: Thank you. I think the second query works its because its the same as the first SQL query is has space after double dash comment operator instead? which is this one I am talking about **where login='admin' -- '** , so this SQL query would work then? **where login='admin' -- ' --'** if you look closely it already has a space after the comment operator.

Comment: It's working because you put space after `--`

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. Thank you for verifying my understanding!